# android.intent.action.phone_state suggestion is not visib;e in manifest file

Tags: android, permissions, broadcastreceiver, manifest

I am encountering a weird behavior in android manifest file. I am working to track incoming calls so added permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

now when i try adding action

```
<receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

PHONE_STATE is not display in manifest suggestions

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
```

Can anyone please help?

Regards,
Bala

Comment: What is the problem? Just type in the action string.

Comment: String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE); This line is throwing a null pointer exception and I believe it is due to <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" /> added in manifest as PHONE_STATE was not visible in suggestion box in manifest file. I am using android studio

Comment: No, it is throwing a `NullPointerException` because `intent` is `null`.